# "Best" svn to hg conversion tool for my specific purposes

Tags: svn, version-control

When it comes to converting from svn to hg it seems like there are a million pages devoted to it (both in stackoverflow and the web in general), but they all seem to have laundry lists about which tools are available, and maybe a recommendation (though they vary, and generally don't really say why it's recommended) but no real information about the factors which would make a tool the best for my requirements. Just as bad much of the info comes from 2010 or so, sometimes with notes or other pages saying "that tool is outdated and/or not well maintained". With hg being rapidly developed 2010 might as well be the stone age.

I want to convert from svn to hg largely for the purposes of simplifying some serious merges. I'd love to convert the whole team to hg, but for various reasons that isn't going to happen yet. So it'll probably be that I'll use hg for sometime, while the rest of the team continues with svn. Therefore it's important for me to be able to round trip, i.e. convert an svn repo to hg, work on hg, then push the changes back to svn. It's also important to be able to sync the hg repository with the svn repo since ongoing changes will be made to the svn repo. While a local hg repo would serve most of my purposes, I'd also like to keep a central one on the server so I can convince other people to try it.

I understand that the main reason DVCS's like hg and git are better at merging is not that they're distributed, but that they keep history in a form that's much more conducive to merging. If I convert an svn repo to hg will hg get enough of that history in its preferred form so that it'll be able to do better merges? What about when I sync?

I don't care about which OS the conversion tool runs on, as we use Windows 7 for our laptops and Linux on the server (which I have superuser access to). If anything I might prefer Linux as that's where the svn repo is and where the central hg repo will be. Nor do I care about how long the initial conversion takes (though sync is another matter) as I can start the conversion on Friday and get in on Monday (our svn repo is just not that big anyway).

Can anyone give me some advice about which svn to hg tools would serve my specific requirements?

Comment: Yes, some merges will be easier (you'll forget about famous "Tree conflicts") for the  cost of some other headaches (related to SVN upstream). Pure Mercurial will be more smooth way

Answer (score 0):

Pure Mercurial (TortoiseHG on Win-box) + [HGSubversion](https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgSubversion)

- Just clone SVN-repo to local Mercurial repo
- Work, commit to Hg
- `hg pull` will be equivalent for `svn up`
- `hg push` will publish changes to SVN-repo

Some notes (dumb quote from `hg help svn` partially):

- When converting from Subversion, hgsubversion does not recognize merge-
  info, and does not create merges based on it.
- Mercurial merges cannot be pushed to Subversion.
  You have to rebase your work on top of SVN HEAD
- Multi-heads branches also can't be pushed (SVN-history is linear, contrary to Hg's DAG)
- It is not possible to interact with more than one Subversion repository
  per Mercurial clone.

**Some notes and observations, that does not fit in comments well**

- SVN does not hide mergeinfo from Mercurial, it's current mainline-HGSubversion, which ignore this data. But even incorrect common parent (in case of HG-merges after SVN-merges) does not prevent neat definition of changed chunks (at least, from memory, "cyclic cross-branches merges" - A->B->C->D->A - isn't problem in HG, contrary to SVN)
- On real SVN projects with Branch Per Task workflow I used SVN-WC and HG-WorkDir in parallel (cloned SVN-repo to local Mercurial, but transfer /mostly after merges/ sources into WC for commits to repo). I prefer separations of Hg and SVN in different places, but, theoretically, it can be common (WD+WC) dir, with the mutual ignoring of foreign metadata

Comment: Thanks. "When converting from Subversion, hgsubversion does not recognize merge- info, and does not create merges based on it." sounds like svn basically loses information that would have been captured by hg. In this case hg may not make my merges much easier, but I'll certainly try it. Maybe I can work on pushing the rest of the team to hg sooner.

Comment: Thanks again. "it's current mainline-HGSubversion, which ignore this data" sounds like there maybe a development version that doesn't do this. Do you know of any? The only thing I could find is the release Revision 538bbb927609 at https://hgsubversion.googlecode.com/hg/.

Comment: @NedLudd - via https://bitbucket.org/seanfarley/hgsubversion/  ("...The biggest feature of this work was the ability to import a merge from a subversion repository...") I found this fork https://bitbucket.org/seanfarley/hgsubversion/ of official extension